# Single Login to Multiple Areas

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, login, user-groups

I am about to migrate a website from Adobe Business Catalyst to Joomla but one of the main items I want to check before doing this is the ability to have different "Restricted Areas" accessible from a Single Login panel.

For example:

- Users A, B & C login and are redirected to pages available in the folder created for Company A.
- Users D, E & F login using the same login panel and are redirected to pages available in the folder created for Company B.

The reason for this is the information available varies from Company to Company and they are co-branded.

Is there a Login plugin or do I need to set this up using different "User Groups" and assigning the User & Pages to the relevant areas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible.

We have a feature called **Access Control List** *(**ACL**)* by default in Joomla!, so you can create simple or complex restricted areas for your content and site sections.

- Here you can find more useful info:
  https://docs.joomla.org/ACL
- Here you have a complete tutorial:
  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial/es

---

Just as a note, the content in joomla! are managed by extensions like components, modules and menu items, not by folders, if you want restricted areas to folders with multimedia (pdf, images, etc) you need [an extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=61&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1) to manage this.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same premise for a single login that takes you to a subdomain?

ie: Login on Main Site > depending on your login, you are redirected to a subdomain. The subdomain would have a Logout button that takes you back to the Main Site.

The reason I am thinking of creating subdomains is because each "sub-site" has its own menu, set of pages and files.

Comment: By default no, this feature works only for the main site, also this depends on how you are managing the subdomains, do you have independent installations for each site?

Comment: Hi Alex, I haven't actually created any subdomains, I was just wondering if it was a better solution to what I need but this could easily be setup. My brief is that we have our own website with general information for the public to view. We then have a dozen+ companies that have a secure section on our domain where they are required to login to view their pages which are branded with their logo. I am wanting to have a single login which then takes them to "their" branded section. I thought creating a menu assigned to a User Group would work but I cant get it working? Menus differ for each.

Comment: Hi there, take a look at this link, here you can find some useful extensions for your requirement: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/multiple-sites